# jQuery UI Slider issues

Tags: jquery

**Resolved**

I've got jQuery slider on my new website build, but I think it's conflicting with other scripts that I am using.

Here is the code I'm using to activate it.

```
    $( "#range" ).slider({
        value:1,
        min: 1,
        max: 20,
        step: 5,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#total" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }

    });
    $( "#total" ).val( "$" + $( "#range" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

HTML:    which is inside the #range div (Ignore the inline styling CMS does it :P)

Now, it adds the "ui classes" and the a tag which acts as the handler but for some reason it's not working i've spent a few hours troubleshooting but im not getting any closer to a resolution.

Comment: It might be a good idea to inform us of the 'other' scripts you are using and list any errors you see in the console - a demo replicating the issue on jsfiddle.net would be best.